# What are the steps of having ROS on a custom robot?

Tags: ros, microcontroller, kinect, motor-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi there,
I'm new to ROS and it was a bit hard for me to start with ROS because I used to program my robots on my own with some languages like C# or C++ and I didn't care about being global and so on.
now I've got a costume robot which has a kinect and some sensors which are connected to some micro-controllers and i can receive their data through Serial-Port.
my question is what are the steps to start with having ROS for my robot?
I mean after I read the tutorials what should I do in general and step by step?
from where should I start?

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71812/what-are-the-steps-of-having-ros-on-a-custom-robot?/) by [SeiedMilad](https://answers.ros.org/users/5824/seiedmilad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

look iRobot Create ([Turtlebot](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_create/tree/groovy/create_node/src/create_node))

my arduino [example](https://github.com/RoboCraft/robot_4wd)

---

Originally posted by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) with karma: 471 on 2013-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-09-09**:
The TurtleBot software, tutorials and examples are definitely good sources of information for starters. Since you are mentioning the serial connection, you might also want to look at [rosserial](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues/49).